# How can I check if there is no free space in the Text component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my canvas component I print text one symbol after another and I need to stop printing if text does not fit. After press next  button other part of the text will be printed. But how can I check if there is no free space in the Text component? I don't need slider here. If all symbols are "i", then I can print 432 of it. And if "w" - then 126.

```
 private IEnumerator TextDelay()
 {
     isTextTyping = true;
     foreach (char i in
         contentToPrint.stringsToPrint[NumberOfStringToPrint])
     {
         if (i != ' ')
             audioTapText.Play();
         textComponent.text += i;
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.04f);
     }
     isTextTyping = false;
 }
```

And I don't want to print half of the word at the end. Then, after press next, print other half

[image]

Comment: I don't have an example at hand, but here's a suggestion. Essentially you want to mask the textview so that it could handle a text of any size, i.e. as if you would make the textview scrollable. Then check in your function if the textview element is larger than your desired boundaries, remove the last characters that were written and return the function prematurely. I doubt that this is the most effecient solution, but it should work.